# Sign in with Gsuite using MVC C# application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, google-authentication, google-workspace

I need to implement Gsuite Login using MVC C# application

I am using below link for the implementation

[Forcing user to sign in with their Google Organization (G Suite) account in mvc c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48806745/forcing-user-to-sign-in-with-their-google-organization-g-suite-account-in-mvc)

I have copied the same code as in above link.

I have added nuget package  Google.Apis.Oauth2.v2 -Version 1.32.1.1103(latest version) into my application but still I am not able to add reference for GoogleOAuth2Client in class file

Could you help me what's wrong here ?

Comment: What do you mean `not able to add reference for GoogleOAuth2Client in class file`? You don't add references to a class file, you use types. Do you get a compilation error? Did you add the correct `using` directives?

Comment: Yes i have added using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2; directory still there is compilation error.

Comment: BTW the link you provided is a *question*, not an implementation guide. It doesn't explain how to implement authentication

Comment: *What* compilation error? People can't guess

Comment: Yes but in the link it's written code is working fine he just want some domain restrictions so i copied it

Comment: Compilation error: The type or namespace name 'GoogleOAuth2Client' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Written code with a *problem*. That's why it's in a question. In any case that doesn't say anything about your compilation error. It doesn't say anything about what you tried, or even if you used the same package, something else, some other version. Post the details and the code in *the question itself*.

Comment: i have mentioned the package i have added in my question which is the latest version and code is same of mentioned link

Comment: *In the question itself* not the comments. Full steps to reproduce the problem and code please. Don't force people to guess

Comment: sure i will add it in my question

Comment: In any case if you simple click on the red squiggly line you'll see the fix light bulb that offers to add the missing `using` directive.

Comment: yes i am aware about it but not getting any suggestion by Intelligence that .net provides

Comment: You still didn't post any helpful information like the code itself. It's impossible to help

Comment: BTW if you wanted to use tha package, why don't you *read its documentation*? There's a developer guide, examples, a full reference at https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/apis/oauth2/v2

Comment: The guide for MVC is [here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#web-applications-aspnet-mvc). The correct package is Google.Apis.Auth.MVC

Comment: There's also a full walkthrough at ASP.NET Core's documentation site: [Google external login setup in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/google-logins?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x)